# jenkins how can I trigger builds when there is a change on gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am trying that Jenkins build my project when there is a change in my GitLab repository. I checked the option

```
Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab CI Service URL: http://172.172.10.21:8090/project/myproject/myproject_frontend
```

and the suboptions

```
Push Events 
Merge Request Events
Rebuild open Merge Request
Comments
Comment for triggering a build
```

Also I checked

```
Check repository (SCM)   ((without schedules))
```

It does not work like this.

what is missing??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the look of it, you are already using [Gitlab Plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitLab+Plugin), you just need to :

- go to your Gitlab repository, go to the "Integrations" section of the repo settings :

[image]

- Then, set the webhook URL as : `https://<jenkins-host>:<port>/project/<your job>` :

[image]

This way Gitlab will perform a `POST` request on your Jenkins Job each time the selected trigger will occur which will trigger your job task if you have configured the specified event to trigger the build.

Comment: Is secret token needed?

Comment: I tried to setup Jenkins job trigger the same way but getting GitLab error "
Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:
  
Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->"

Comment: I am facing same error as like @Lyserty when I test the webhook I created in GitLab. Any idea how to get rid of this error?